# Add timestamp to filename in StaxEventItemWriter

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have the following Spring Batch itemwriter that streams to a file, but wish to add a timestamp to the filename.
The following code works but is incorrect, because the timestamp is set at startup time rather than on every batch run.
What I like to achieve is that a new filename gets assigned on every job run, any idea how to do this?

```
@Component
public class EccAddSumoItemWriter extends SumoStaxEventItemWriter<AddSubscriptionXml> {

    public static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss.SSS");

    public EccAddSumoItemWriter(@Value("${sumo.output_folder}") String sumoSavePath) {
        setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(true);
        setRootIdentification("editionCodeChanged_add");
        setResourcePath(sumoSavePath + "/edition_code_changed_add-" + now().format(DATE_FORMATTER) + ".xml");
    }

}
```

`setResourcePath` merely refers to:

```
protected void setResourcePath(String resourceFilePath) {
    this.setResource(new FileSystemResource(resourceFilePath));
}
```

What is the advised way of doing this in Spring Batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the theory it seems that simply `@StepScope` should resolve the problem.
I will test this.

After test, worked perfectly:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ditch your `EccAddSumoItemWriter` and write an `@Bean` method that creates a `@StepScope` or `@JobScope` `SumoStaxEventItemWriter`.

```java
@StepScope
@Bean
public SumoStaxEventItemWriter writer(@Value("${sumo.output_folder}") String sumoSavePath) {
  SumoStaxEventItemWriter writer = new SumoStaxEventItemWriter();
  writer.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(true);
  writer.setRootIdentification("editionCodeChanged_add");
  writer.setResourcePath(sumoSavePath + "/edition_code_changed_add-" + now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss.SSS")) + ".xml");
  return writer;
}
```

Now when building your step use this step scoped writer and each time you will get a fresh instance configured accordingly.

Comment: Many thanks, but you answered what I already did... The @Bean annotation is merely a convenience (which btw I do not prefer as it adds configuration for an otherwise already present class), it is a preference. But I gave you +1 for taking the time. Thanks.